# i want to obfuscate AndroidManifest.xml with Proguard

Tags: android, android-manifest, proguard

Can i obfuscate AndroidManifest.xml file with Proguard?

i think write to source code in my proguard.config file.
(-adaptresourcefilenames    AndroidManifest.xml)

but it wasn't work.

Comment: You could change the class names to some random strings using a custom ant build script. I don't think it would make sense to obfuscate anything else in there.

Answer (score 20):

The standard Android release builds only apply ProGuard to the compiled bytecode, not to any resource files. It therefore can't adapt files like  AndroidManifest.xml.

Moreover, these build processes first run `aapt` to convert AndroidManifest.xml and other XML files to binary versions, for more efficient packaging and use. Aapt also writes out some configuration for ProGuard. ProGuard can only parse and adapt resource files in text format, so it wouldn't work on the binary versions.

[DexGuard](http://www.saikoa.com/dexguard), the commercial extension of ProGuard that specifically targets Android, streamlines the build process. It also obfuscates and optimizes the binary XML files, as far as possible. As Nikolay mentioned, some class names still can't be obfuscated; notably the ones that may be referenced from other apps.

(I am the developer of ProGuard and DexGuard)

Comment: Dexguard is veryyyyyyyyyy expansive and the price is not available unless you asked for. I think you have to make versions of DexGuard tailored for everyone needs, version for obfuscating only ressources ....

Comment: if this is true how come I need to add this rule `-keepresourcexmlattributenames manifest/**`  to stop pro-guard breaking the auto-verification (AppLink) part of an intent filter

Answer (score 1):

You can't: the system needs to know about your components (activities, services, etc.) You can't obfuscate the names of components references in the manifest either. The default ProGuard configuration excludes those explicitly.

Comment: app named manifest viewer can show all the details of androidmanifest of app. But I can see there are couple of apps for which it does not show all the details. Apps like medium - its manifest details are hidden while quora's manifest details are visible. So I guess there is some mechanism by which we can hide the details of androidmanifest.

Comment: You can, It should be possible to rename all services and activities in Manifest and code as well.